# SQL Express -- Cleaning House, Automation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When we develop an ASP.NET client site, we deploy a SQL Server Express database along with it.  We need to run a clean-up script to check for records older than n. hours, but unfortunately I cannot schedule a job do to the limitations of SQL Express.  Are there any other alternatives or suggestions for automating clean-house that anyone may have had experience implementing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [conversation timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) and run the maintenance from an [activated procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx). Sign the procedure for [cross-db or server wide access](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/).

The big advantage is that is self contained in the database and survives across database copy and backup/restore operations (a scheduled 'job' will execute after a restore on a new system).

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Windows Scheduled Task that hits an ASP.NET page to do the clean up.

Comment: Or a Windows scheduled task that *just* performs the clean up (no page hittage needed)

Comment: I would use the web page because a) let's you run remotely if you need to, and b) keeps your code in the same place...